# el insert de phpmyadmin no se guarda

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

tengo un problema

resulta que quiero crear una tabla de usuarios que se registren y logeen pero no me inserta nada y me da un script el cual yo puse en caso que no se guardara nada el cual me dice que no se registro usuario
el insert lo ejecute bien en php y si me lo dio pero no se porque aqui no me lo da lo esty ejecutando con mysql worbench lo conecte local y cheque las conexiones si las tengo bien hechas
aca el codigo
nota las bases son idusuario, nombre,correo,usuario,password

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
//login
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $usuario =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['user']);
    $password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['pass']);
    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
    $sql = "SELECT idusuarios from usuarios where usuario = '' AND password = '' ";
    $resultado = $conexion -> query ($sql);
    $rows= $resultado -> num_rows;
    if ($rows > 0 ){
        $row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION ['id_usuario'] = $row ["idusuarios"];
        header ("location : admin.php");

    }else {
        echo "<script>
        alert ('usuario o password incorrecto');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";

    }



}



//registrar usuario
if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nombre']);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['correo']);
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['user']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['pass']);
    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
    $sqluser ="SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios where usuario ='$usuario'";

    $resultadouser=$conexion->query($sqluser);

    $filas= $resultadouser->num_rows;
    if($filas > 0){
        echo "<script>
        alert ('El usuario ya existe');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";
    }else{
        $sqlusuario="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre', '$correo','$usuario','$password_encriptada')";
       if($resultadousuario > 0 ){
        echo "<script>
        alert ('registro exitoso');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";
       }else {
        echo "<script>
        alert ('error al registrarse');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
       }
    }





}

?>


<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" >
        <fieldset>
            <label class="block clearfix">
                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="user" placeholder="Usuario" />
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                </span>
            </label>

            <label class="block clearfix">
                <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                    <input type="password" name="pass"class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" />
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                </span>
            </label>

            <div class="space"></div>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <label class="inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                    <span class="lbl"> Recordarme</span>
                </label>

    <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
        <span class="bigger-110">Ingresar</span>
    </button>


            </div>

            <div class="space-4"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

                                            <div class="social-or-login center">
                                                <span class="bigger-110">Suscribete</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="space-6"></div>

                                            <div class="social-login center">
                                                <a 
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-youtube" ></i>
                                                </a>
                                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/impartiendoconocimiento" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                                </a>

                                                <a href="https://twitter.com/jasingafi" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info">
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                                </a>

                                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jasingafi/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.widget-main -->

                                        <div class="toolbar clearfix">
                                            <div>
                                                <a href="#" data-target="#forgot-box" class="forgot-password-link">
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                                    Olvide mi contraseña
                                                </a>
                                            </div>

                                            <div>
                                                <a href="#" data-target="#signup-box" class="user-signup-link">
                                                    Nuevo Registro
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.login-box -->

                                <div id="forgot-box" class="forgot-box widget-box no-border">
                                    <div class="widget-body">
                                        <div class="widget-main">
                                            <h4 class="header red lighter bigger">
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
                                                Recuperar Contraseña
                                            </h4>

                                            <div class="space-6"></div>
                                            <p>
                                                ingresa tu correo electronico para recibir las instrucciones
                                            </p>

                        <form>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="block clearfix">
                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                                <span class="bigger-110">Enviar</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                </div><!-- /.widget-main -->

    <div class="toolbar center">
        <a href="#" data-target="#login-box" class="back-to-login-link">
            Regresar al Login
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
            </div>
            </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
            </div><!-- /.forgot-box -->

    <div id="signup-box" class="signup-box widget-box no-border">
                <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="widget-main">
                <h4 class="header green lighter bigger">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users blue"></i>
                        Registro de Nuevos Usuarios
                </h4>
    <div class="space-6"></div>
        <p>Ingresa los datos solicitados acontinuacion: </p>
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" >
            <fieldset>
                        <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo"  required />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="Email"  required />
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>
                    <label class="block clearfix">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario"  required />
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                </label>
                <label class="block clearfix">
                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  required />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passr" placeholder="Repetir password" />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-retweet"></i>
                                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                        <span class="lbl">
                        Acepto los
                        <a href="#">Terminos de Uso</a>
                        </span>
                </label>
                <div class="space-24"></div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="reset" class="width-30 pull-left btn btn-sm">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh"></i>
                            <span class="bigger-110">Reset</span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="submit" name="registrar"   class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
                        <span class="bigger-110">Registrar</span>
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
                    </button>
                     </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

            <div class="toolbar center">

                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                        Regresar al Login
                </a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
    </div><!-- /.signup-box -->
</div><!-- /.position-relative -->
```

este es el codigo que incluse cambie varias veces 
y las conexiones a database

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de la tabla usuarios?

Answer (score 0):

El detalle es que no estas ejecutando la inserción/query

Solo estas guardando tu query en tu variable `$sqlusuario`

```
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre', '$correo','$usuario','$password_encriptada')";
    $resultadousuario=$conexion->query($sqlusuario); // te falta esta linea en tu código
    if ($resultadousuario > 0) {
        echo "<script>
        alert ('registro exitoso');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert ('error al registrarse');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
    }
```